# Display images from API In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display images from my API which are in objects. I am using a react-multi-carousel. Currently, I can get it to work if I am pulling in a single object, but when I try to access the array it does not work. So If I use `src={post.home.image}` it works. But If I try `src={post.image}` it does not work.

My code so far is:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import '../slider/slider.css';
  import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
  import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";

  const responsive = {
      superLargeDesktop: {
          breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
          items: 1,
      },
      desktop: {
          breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
          items: 1,
      },
      tablet: {
          breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
          items: 1,
      },
      mobile: {
          breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
          items: 1,
      },
  };

  class Slider extends Component {
      state = {
          awsApiData: []
      }

      componentDidMount() {
          console.log('app mounted');
          /*global fetch */
          fetch('https://onelbip0e6.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/livestage/xxx')
              .then(data => data.json())
              .then(data => this.setState({ awsApiData: data }, () => console.log(data)));
      }

      render() {
          return (
              <div>
                        <Carousel
                            additionalTransfrom={0}
                            showDots={false}
                            arrows={true}
                            autoPlaySpeed={3000}
                            autoPlay={false}
                            centerMode={false}
                            className="carousel-hero"
                            containerClass="container-with-dots"
                            dotListClass="dots"
                            draggable
                            focusOnSelect={false}
                            infinite
                            itemClass="carousel-top"
                            keyBoardControl
                            minimumTouchDrag={80}
                            renderButtonGroupOutside={false}
                            renderDotsOutside
                            responsive={responsive}>
                            {this.state.awsApiData.map((post, indx) => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="mt-5" key={indx}>
                                        <img className="media-img card-img-top card-img-hero" src={post.image} alt="Alt text"></img>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })}
                        </Carousel>
                        </div>
          );
      }
  }

  export default Slider;
```

**API Schema**

```
[
  {
    "home": {
      "title": "Home",
      "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/1280x600.jpg"
    },
    "about": {
      "title": "About",
      "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/1280x600.jpg"
    }
  }
]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That looks like an API data sample, and not really the schema, correct?

Comment: "So If I use `src={post.home.image}` it works. But If I try `src={post.image}` it does not work. " So do the thing that works.

Comment: Are you sure about that schema? That's an array of length 1 that contains a single object with 2 keys. Did you intend to have an array of length 2 containing 2 objects with one key each?

Comment: @ajaybee can you show example of your version of the schema and implementation, at the moment the answer marked works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have this JSON Schema, you have to follow the following code changes.

```
.then(data => this.setState({ awsApiData: data[0] }, () => console.log(data[0])));
```

```js
{Object.values(this.state.awsApiData).map((post, indx) => {
  return (
      <div className="mt-5" key={indx}>
          <img className="media-img card-img-top card-img-hero" src={post.image} alt="Alt text"></img>
      </div>
  );
})}
```

Comment: That did it, but why do you have to use `[0]` I thought this was only used to target first element

Comment: yes it targets first element. if you see the JSON schema, it has only one item which is a object in the array. then we have to extract the images from that object.

Comment: @Sole `[0]` is necessary because your data is a list with a single element.

Answer (score 1):

It is the structure of API that caused you the issue. In this API response case, setting component state to awsApiData: data or awsApiData: data[0] will not help.
Instead run `Object.values(data[0])`. This gives an array of objects(internal - values of home and about keys ). You can then use the map method and access the image as post.image

Try this out. If my answer resolves the issue, please accept this as answer